Next.JS parallel routes share context
I have the following folder structure with Next.JS

app/

@aside/

users

[userId]/

todos

new








@main/

users

[userId]/

todos

new








layout.tsx



I need to wrap both parallel routes (aside and main) in a single context that depends on a route parameter (userId). Is there any way I can do this without reaching for a global state manager like redux?
// layout.tsx

interface LayoutProps {
  aside: React.ReactNode;
  main: React.ReactNode;
}

export default function Layout({ aside, main }: LayoutProps) {
  return (
    <div>
      {aside}
      {main}
    </div>
  );
}

// TodoFormContext.tsx

type ContextValue = {
  form: UseFormReturn<TodoFormValue>;
};

const Context = React.createContext<ContextValue | null>(null);

export interface TodoFormProviderProps {
  user: User;
  children: React.ReactNode;
}

export function TodoFormProvider({ user, children }: TodoFormProviderProps) {
  const form = defaultForUser(user);
  const contextValue = useMemo(() => ({ form }), [form]);
  return <Context.Provider value={contextvalue}>{children}</Context.Provider>;
}

export function useTodoFormContext() {
  const context = useContext(Context);
  if (context === null) {
    throw new Error(
      "useTodoFormContext() must be used within <TodoFormProvider/>"
    );
  }
  return context;
}

// ./@aside/users/[userId]/todos/new
export default function NewUserTodoAside() {
  const { form } = useTodoFormContext();
  return <aside>{/* ... */}</aside>;
}

// ./@main/users/[userId]/todos/new
export default function NewUserTodoMain() {
  const { form } = useTodoFormContext();
  return <main>{/* ... */}</main>;
}


render the provider in layout.tsx

layout.tsx doesn't have access to the route params though (userId won't be available for some routes)

You can read searchParams in the provider via useSearchParams

I think the structure should be in this way
/app
 page
 layout.tsx
 @aside
  default.tsx (reason to use because page will reference to the exact same route that matching to /, if you are planing to use @aside route in all route, using default may be a good option for you)
 @main
  default.tsx
 /user/[id]/todos/new
 page.tsx

the layout file code :
export default function Layout({
  main, aside, children
}: {
  user: React.ReactNode
  aside: React.ReactNode
  children: React.ReactNode
}) {
  
  return <>
{main}
{children}
{aside}
</>
}
    

 

